# Build error despite having the correct Kotlin version

Tags: android, config, android-jetpack-compose

It's ridiculous, that I am getting this error, when I do have: `id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false`

**Update:** Everything worked fine all day. The moment, I decided to incorporate this, https://dagger.dev/hilt/, that's when problems began to occur. Not sure of why, I followed all the instructions on the website.

**Android Installed:**

[image]

**Error:**

```
> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
e: This version (1.1.1) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.6.10 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.6.21 which is not known to be compatible.  Please fix your configuration (or `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` but don't say I didn't warn you!).

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 648ms
28 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 27 up-to-date
```

---

**build.gradle (Project):**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.1.1'
        coroutines = '1.6.4'
        accompanist = '0.24.13-rc' // https://github.com/google/accompanist
        datastore = '1.0.0' // https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/datastore
        room = '2.4.2'
        navigation = '2.5.0'
        lifecycle = '2.5.0' // https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle
        material3 = '1.0.0-alpha14' // https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3
        work = '2.7.1' // https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work
        rcview = '1.2.1' // https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/recyclerview
        rcview_select = '1.1.0'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.42'
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$navigation"
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

---

**build.gradle(Module):**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id "kotlin-kapt"
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments += [
                        "room.schemaLocation":"$projectDir/schemas".toString(),
                        "room.incremental":"true",
                        "room.expandProjection":"true"
                ]
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerVersion "1.6.10"
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:$datastore"

    // Coroutines
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines"

    // Work
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work"

    // optional - Paging 3 Integration
    implementation "androidx.room:room-paging:2.5.0-alpha02"

    // Navigation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigation"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigation"

    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$navigation"

    // Testing Navigation
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$navigation"

    // Jetpack Compose Integration
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$navigation"

    // status bar customization
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-systemuicontroller:0.23.1"

    // Accompanist
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager:0.23.0" // Pager
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager-indicators:0.23.0" // Pager Indicators

    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$rcview"
    // For control over item selection of both touch and mouse driven selection
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:$rcview_select"

    // Card view
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"

    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.42'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.42'
    //implementation("com.google.devtools.ksp:symbol-processing-api:1.6.10-1.0.6")

    // For instrumentation tests
    androidTestImplementation  'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.42'
    kaptAndroidTest 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.42'

    // For local unit tests
    testImplementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.42'
    kaptTest 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.42'

    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room")
    annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room")

    // To use Kotlin annotation processing tool (kapt)
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room")

    // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room")


    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.animation:animation-graphics:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:$material3"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class:$material3"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle"
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version"
}
```

---

**settings.gradle**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
android.useAndroidX=true
kotlin.code.style=official
android.nonTransitiveRClass=true
android.enableJetifier=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
kapt.correctErrorTypes=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
android.lifecycleProcessor.incremental=true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `build.gradle` (module) file there's a line `kotlinCompilerVersion "1.6.10"` under `composeOptions`, change it to match your Kotlin version `1.6.21`.

Comment: I solved it, the problem was somewhere else. Took a while, thank you.